# Which of the two identical hard disks is mounted?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I ordered new Debian web server which has 2 hard disks. I assume that one of them should be partitioned and mounted. The problem is that I cannot identify which one should be partitioned and mounted and which one has all the Ubuntu files. Here are the results of several commands which I could not get the answer, perhaps due to lack of knowledge in Ubuntu.

```
# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   477G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sda2    8:2    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sda3    8:3    0 444.4G  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0 444.3G  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0   477G  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdb2    8:18   0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb3    8:19   0 444.4G  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0 444.3G  0 raid1 /


# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0ba4900f

Device     Boot    Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           2048   67110911  67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       67110912   68159487   1048576   512M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       68159488 1000213167 932053680 444.4G fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x31fd01ce

Device     Boot    Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048   67110911  67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2       67110912   68159487   1048576   512M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       68159488 1000213167 932053680 444.4G fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 32 GiB, 34326183936 bytes, 67043328 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/md1: 511.4 MiB, 536281088 bytes, 1047424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/md2: 444.3 GiB, 477077241856 bytes, 931791488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


# blkid
/dev/sdb1: UUID="4374a69b-c5ca-ceee-bfd3-3df61d255a13" UUID_SUB="f1ca2293-d87d-83b8-dad9-aba968c25d0a" LABEL="rescue:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="0ba4900f-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="4b93d869-e581-7187-70ca-c4f9e7668ed5" UUID_SUB="6921e275-a6f3-0e5f-52c6-37520265266e" LABEL="rescue:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="0ba4900f-02"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="10c95f64-534c-e940-f016-77851637282b" UUID_SUB="003339b6-34c6-a11c-0f95-722934e2cd25" LABEL="rescue:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="0ba4900f-03"
/dev/sda1: UUID="4374a69b-c5ca-ceee-bfd3-3df61d255a13" UUID_SUB="865a9479-0077-b93e-fde5-62b4427eed93" LABEL="rescue:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="31fd01ce-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="4b93d869-e581-7187-70ca-c4f9e7668ed5" UUID_SUB="fade36f5-1a58-9645-4c8e-d3bbbadb2d4d" LABEL="rescue:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="31fd01ce-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="10c95f64-534c-e940-f016-77851637282b" UUID_SUB="75c16690-bce6-0f66-1a6f-4819b70fb1bd" LABEL="rescue:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="31fd01ce-03"
/dev/md0: UUID="2317882d-d15e-4879-8eab-8d37b77b717e" TYPE="swap"
/dev/md1: UUID="6ef84344-8aa2-4807-9486-4c98ab3aeffa" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/md2: UUID="a710dcc5-e25f-452b-bffd-486bb9eba812" TYPE="ext4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are mounted simultaneously.  That is because they are both part of a single RAID1 disk array, which is referenced as `/dev/md{0,1,2}` for the actual 'partitions' being used for the actual 'devices' which store disk data (for `/boot`, `/`, swap space, etc.)

This is a setup where you're using `mdadm` or such and have the two drives together as part of a software-based RAID1 array.  That's why you see in `fdisk -l` the "Linux raid autodetect" filesystem type.

The two disks are 'identical' because of the RAID1 restriction on mapped disk space - you'd need two identical disks to get true RAID1, and that's what you have here.  (And though this is not **true** RAID which is done at the hardware level with RAID controllers, this is a software-driven RAID array that achieves the same type of setup).

Comment: Thank you @Thomas for the quick answer. If they are both mounted, then it turns out that no further actions are required. If so, I need to have 1 TB space (512GB + 512 GB). Why I see only 512 GB?

Comment: As I understand they pretend to be one single 512 GB hard drive and this is done for the performance of the server. But I need to have 1 GB space so I need to split them into two different hard disks. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: @Ulugbek Since you are using a RAID1 configuration, the drives are mirrored (exact duplicates of each other).  If you need 1TB of space you will either need 2 more drives or delete the RAID configuration and use the /dev/sd* devices.

Comment: @stumblebee Thank you. As I understand, I need to delete RAID configuration and then do partitioning and mounting. Is there any documentation or tutorial for this procedure?

Comment: @Ulugbek I don't believe there's any documentation for deconfiguring the RAID.  Especially considering that deconfiguring the raid *could* torch the data that's already present there, so you need to back up the data before you attempt to deconfigure the RAID, then reconfigure mount points, then reconfigure `grub` to properly boot... (and a list of other things, all of which is pretty non-trivial to do...)

Comment: Also, you might not be able to deconfigure the RAID, if this is a VPS or some type of server where deconfiguring the RAID would destroy the environment.  You don't specify if it's a physical server you got, or a dedicated server run by another provider, or a VPS, or anything, so there's a chance that it *needs* to be configured this way